# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked in Batch Insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite, batch-insert

I am doing a batch insert with the following method

```
module DatabaseHelper

  ActionHelper = ActionController::Base.helpers
  CONN = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

  def self.mass_sql_insert(klass, columns, values, batch_size = 500)
    table = klass.constantize.table_name if klass.constantize.kind_of?(Class)
    values.each_slice(batch_size) do |batch|
      sql = ActionHelper.sanitize("INSERT INTO #{table} (#{columns.join(', ')}) VALUES #{batch.join(', ')}")
      CONN.execute sql
    end
  end
```

This method was working great, but just recently started throwing the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked:
```

What follows this error is the sql insert command that I'm trying to perform. When I put that straight into a dbconsole, it works fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is not really supposed to be used for concurrent access which is the issue you are running into here. You can try increasing the timeout in your `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/my_dev.sqlite3
  timeout: 10000
```

better to use another db engine for improving concurrency

Comment: Just increasing the time does not solve my issue. what about changing the pool size so that it doesn't try to use concurrent access...? Any other suggestions